# WinServer 2008 R2 MySQL cluster service won't start

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-cluster, mysql5.5

So I have a two-node failover cluster in WinServer 2008 R2, I also created a generic service which will manage my MySQL5.5 database (the database root is also in a iSCSI storage).

When the cluster carries to the other node, the MySQL generic service won't start, I have found somewhat a fix to the problem by deleting the 3 log_files in the database root then manually bringing the service online again, but when the cluster switches to the other node, I have to perform the process again.

Is there any permanent way which can fix this problem? I don't want to delete the files everytime the cluster failovers.

TIA!

Comment: I had no idea that MySQL officially supported WFC. Are you sure that this is supposed to work out of the box without an commercial version of MySQL?

Comment: They do actually, although I am not sure when did MySQL started supporting WFC. [link](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-with-windows-server-2008-r2-failover-clustering/)http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-with-windows-server-2008-r2-failover-clustering/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved this one, I just followed the MySQL manual and also with a couple of server restarts.

The MySQL WFC manual can be found [here](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-with-windows-server-2008-r2-failover-clustering/).

Cheers!